# Express the following limit as a definite integral (Riemann Sums)

Tags: integration

> The limit is following : $$\underset{n \to \infty}{\lim}  ∑ \frac{(n^3+i^3)}{n^4}.$$

I've figured out that good candidate for integration interval is [0,1] taking 1 as a b. Also I've manipulated the following integral by separating sum in numerator, but it made me no further.

Thank You for Your help in advance.

Comment: Can you explain the problem in more detail please? As of now it is unclear what you are asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\underset { n\to \infty  }{ \lim   } ∑\frac { (n^{ 3 }+i^{ 3 }) }{ n^{ 4 } } =\underset { n\to \infty  }{ \lim   } \frac { 1 }{ n } ∑\left( 1+{ \left( \frac { i }{ n }  \right)  }^{ 3 } \right) =\int _{ 0 }^{ 1 }{ \left( 1+{ x }^{ 3 } \right)  } dx={ \left( x+\frac { { x }^{ 4 } }{ 4 }  \right)  }_{ 0 }^{ 1 }=\frac { 5 }{ 4 }  $$

Comment: Can You explain me why we factored out the 1/n before the limit? I would be truly grateful.

Comment: it was typo i have fixed it already)

Comment: And 1/n is constructed as b-a/n, where b is 1, and a is 0? I was very close to this one but i was lacking of idea how to proceed. Thank You.

Comment: yes ,exactly.you're welcome)

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum\frac{(n^3+i^3)}{n^4} =\dfrac1n\sum_{i=1}^n1+\dfrac1n\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\dfrac in\right)^3$$

$$\text{Use }\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac1n\sum_{r=1}^n f\left(\frac rn\right)=\int_0^1f(x)dx$$  for the second part.

What about the first?